# How to Get scales in ggplot after initial plot layer generated

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I've looked for an answer to this, but have not found one - 
I use ggplot2 to draw a series of densities 
after  I draw them, I need to obtain the x and y scales, so that I can annotate in the upper left corner - here is my code:

```
gg= qplot(ExpRef,geom='density',color=IOL,fill=IOL,alpha=0.8,data=tmp2,
        main=mtitle,xlab ="Expected Refraction",cex.axis=3.0,font.axis = 2)  #bold and cesx = multiplier);
ggp = gg + geom_vline(data=data.frame(x=0,y=0),xintercept=means, lwd= 2,color=I("red")) ;
ggp = gg + geom_vline(data=data.frame(x=0,y=0),xintercept=PlanRef, lwd= 2,color=I("green")) ;
ggp = ggp + annotate("text",x=PlanRef, y = 1,  label=paste('Planned Refraction'),angle=90,size=7.0,colour='black', hjust = 0, vjust = 0)

ggp = ggp + annotate("text",x=SRKTRef, y = 0,label=paste('SRKT IOL-->'),angle=90,size=6.0,colour='yellow', hjust = 0, vjust = 0);
```

- So in the last line I need to know the max of y to place the annotation in the upper part of the graphic - is there a way to get the scales that were computed in the density graph layer?
  thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a simplified example in your question that is fully reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

for annotations at the borders of the plotting region, you can use `-Inf` (left / bottom) or `+Inf` (right / top):

```
qplot(1:10, rnorm(10)) + 
annotate("text", x=Inf, y=-Inf, 
         label="bottom-right", vjust=-0.5, hjust=1)
```

Comment: Thanks - that should work, but I would still like access to the scales

Comment: scales will change as you add new layers, but once the ggplot is complete you can do `ggplot_build(p)` and extract the scales from there.